# Programar video Loop en Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

he diseñado una pantalla de bienvenida con un background video de fondo.
Quisiera saber como crear un loop para que cuando termine se repita de manera infinita.

Actualmente dispongo del siguiente codigo con sus respectivas funciones, muchas gracias por su ayuda.

```
@IBOutlet weak var vwPlayer: UIView!

var player: AVPlayer?
    
    override init(frame:CGRect){
        super.init(frame:frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    required init?(coder:NSCoder){
        super.init(coder:coder)
        commonInit()
    }

fileprivate func commonInit() {
    let viewFromXib = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("VideoPlayer", owner: self, options: nil)![0] as! UIView
    viewFromXib.frame = self.bounds
    addSubview(viewFromXib)
    addPlayerToView(self.vwPlayer)
    
}

fileprivate func addPlayerToView(_ view: UIView) {
    player = AVPlayer()
    let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    playerLayer.frame = self.bounds
    playerLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
    view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(playerEndPlay), name: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: nil)

}

func playVideoWithFileName(_ fileName: String, offtype type: String) {
    guard let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: fileName, ofType: type) else {return}
    let videoURL = URL (fileURLWithPath: filePath)
    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: videoURL)
    player?.replaceCurrentItem(with: playerItem)
    player?.play()
    
}
```

Comment: En la documentación de Apple menciona esta clase [AVPlayerLooper](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayerlooper).

Comment: Gracias mi amigo, echare un vistazo.

Comment: por favor revisa el tema de constraints en la parte de commonInit en lugar de usar frames y lee esta pregunta https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29386531/how-to-detect-when-avplayer-video-ends-playing